# How to do DroidParts to Realm Migration for Non-primitive Data Structure?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, realm, database-migration

Three years back we used Droidparts library to save the data,We have decided to change database from Droidparts to Realm Database. We are able to pull the data for Primitive datatype. Incase of Non-Primitive data structures like(ArrayList) we are facing issues because Realm doesn't support for Non-Primitive data structures.

Please suggest me possible solution ?

Comment: Have you considered using RealmList? like,RealmList<ClassName> classObject;

Answer (score 0):

It would be clear if you can state what you mean by non-Primitive. (Is it a boxed type number value?, or user defined class?)

In case of custom class and boxed type number value, Realm support list of those types out of box. You can take a look at [the latest document](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many) for more detail.

Comment: DroidParts can save list data with '|' this separator. I need those values (Object IDs). I need to convert those Droidparts objects  Realm objects.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you illustrate with a piece of code, please?